# formatted Input from file in Python

Tags: python, nltk

i'm trying to read a file into my python program and apply tokenizer on it to split the text into a set of sentences. However, in my output i'm getting the '/n' character that i'd like to avoid in the output, as it might hinder my further processes on the sentences. 
I read the input using the read() command. Also tried readline(). i'm still getting the newline characters on my output. Any suggestions on avoiding this?

```
file_sent = open(path,'r')
all_sents = file_sent.read()
sent_all = print all_sents
tokenized_sents = sent_tokenize(sent_all)
```

Comment: "\n" is the text symbol for linebreak.

Comment: I know that But I dont want it on my input.

Comment: That code should not run.  The line `sent_all = print all_sents` causes an "invalid syntax" error.  What are you doing to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove the newlines entirely:

```
all_sents = file_sent.read().replace('\n', '')
```

If you want to replace them with spaces:

```
all_sents = file_sent.read().replace('\n', ' ')
```

Obviously you could replace them with something else if you wanted.

Comment: that's true, thanks! But I was wondering if there's any other way we could do the same.

Comment: What exactly other kind of way are you thinking of?  You could to it at some other point in the processing. For example, if you split it into words, you could use `.split()` which will work fine with any kind of whitespace including newlines, and they will go away at that point.